# How to create an empty copy of a 2D array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm working on a project where I need to create an empty copy of a 2D array in JavaScript. I have an original array filled with the number of days in a month:

```
var originalArray = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 
    [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14], 
    [15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21], 
    [22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28], 
    [29, 30, 31]
];
```

Expected result:

```
copiedArray = [
    [, , , , , , ], 
    [, , , , , , ], 
    [, , , , , , ], 
    [, , , , , , ], 
    [, , ]
];
```

How do I create a new empty array with the exact number of elements as the original array?
Thanks in advance!

I've tried a nested loop but not successful.

Comment: Woah woah woah, do you want an *empty* array or just an array filled with `undefined`?

Comment: Just an empty array. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

something like this?

```js
var originalArray = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 
    [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14], 
    [15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21], 
    [22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28], 
    [29, 30, 31]
];

const copiedArray = originalArray.map(a => Array(a.length).fill())

console.log(copiedArray)
```

Answer (score 3):

like this

```js
const originalArray = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 
    [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14], 
    [15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21], 
    [22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28], 
    [29, 30, 31]
];

const copiedArray = originalArray.map(row => {
  return new Array(row.length);
});

console.log( copiedArray );
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try this ?

```
var copiedArray = new Array(originalArray.length);
for (var i = 0; i < originalArray.length; i++) {
    copiedArray[i] = new Array(originalArray[i].length);
}
```

if you want to make it recursive you can also do it like this :

```
function createEmptyCopy(array) {
  var copiedArray = new Array(array.length);
  
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (Array.isArray(array[i])) {
      copiedArray[i] = createEmptyCopy(array[i]);
    } else {
      copiedArray[i] = undefined;
    }
  }
  
  return copiedArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    let newArray = originalArray.map(row => row.map(column => ""))
```

The line above seems to do the job like you said. If you want to change the empty string to null or undefined, it will still work without any issues. You can run an example below to see whether it is upto your specs or not.

```js
let originalArray = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 
    [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14], 
    [15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21], 
    [22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28], 
    [29, 30, 31]
];

let newArray = originalArray.map(row => row.map(column => ""))

console.log(newArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.from` and `fill()` like this:

```js
const original = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
    [15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21],
    [22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28],
    [29, 30, 31]
];

const copied = Array.from(original, el => Array(el.length).fill());

console.log(copied);
```